# Xcode iOs Simulator - native websites check before going online

Tags: xcode, simulator

I am downloading the Xcode from the app store to check how my websites will look on different devices. I know how to use the iOS simulator but for websites that are already online. Is there a way to check how a website looks like when i have it native on my mac? I mean when i am at the development stage of the website before put it online, is there a way  to check it on the iOs simulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator contains a version of Safari that can access the outside world via your Mac's network connection. So you don't have to do anything — just type in the address as with any other browser.

You can also drag and drop local HTML content (or anything else the simulator's miniaturised suite of apps can handle) directly onto the simulator to preview without uploading anywhere.

Comment: so if i have an html and a css file inside a folder i can drag the folder to simulator and it will read both the html and the css files?

Comment: I believe you'd drag the HTML only — all it does is construct an appropriate `file://` URL and open that in [Mobile] Safari. The simulator has the same access to your Mac's filing system as any other Mac app.